# Hyperref stops zref from picking the appropriate counter

Tags: hyperref, counters, incompatibility, zref

[`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `counter` module allows one to track which counter was (ref)stepped, similar in functionality to [`autoref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/autoref). The property keeping track of this counter is aptly called `counter`.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-user,zref-counter}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Section counter: \zref[counter]{sec:label}\par
Figure counter: \zref[counter]{fig:label}

\section{A section}\zlabel{sec:label}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure.}\zlabel{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) loaded, the counter outputs resemble:

[image]

Without `hyperref` loaded, the counter outputs resemble:

[image]

How can I make `hyperref` not influence the setting of the appropriate property value for `counter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a class I wrote I used this to get around this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-user,zref-counter}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\refstepcounter{%
 \zref@setcurrent{counter}{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

Section counter: \zref[counter]{sec:label}\par
Figure counter: \zref[counter]{fig:label}

\section{A section}\zlabel{sec:label}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure.}\zlabel{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

An alternative is to add a patch after loading hyperref (and before loading cleveref):

```
\makeatletter
 \ZREF@patch{H@refstepcounter}{%
    \def\H@refstepcounter#1{%
      \zref@setcurrent{counter}{#1}%
      \ZREF@org@H@refstepcounter{#1}%
    }%
  }%
\makeatother
```

I did sent Heiko a message about this problem end of last year but forgot to check if something happened about it.